# Why cannot CMake functions return values?

Tags: cmake

A question for CMake experts out-there.
According to the CMake [function documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/function.html) a function simply does not return anything. To change variable values one has to pass it to the function, and inside the function set the new value specifying the `PARENT_SCOPE` option.
Fine, this is a well-known feature of CMake.

My question here is not about the *how*, rather on *why*: why CMake functions do not return values? What is the idea behind?
For example, a function cannot be used inside a `if` expression, or called inside a `set` command.
If I remember correctly, it is the same with autotools, therefore I do not think it is like this just by chance.

Is there any expert that knows *why*?

Answer (score 5):

You can find a partial answer by [Ken Martin](http://www.kitware.com/ken-martin/) in a [message](http://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-November/025423.html) from the CMake's mailing list:

> With respect to the general question of functions returning values it
>   could be done but it is a bit of a big change.  Functions and commands
>   look the same (and should act the same IMO) to the people using them.
>   So really we are talking about commands returning values. This is
>   mostly just a syntax issue. Right now we have

```
command(arg arg arg
)
```

> to support return values we need something that could handle

```
command (arg command2(arg arg) arg arg 
)
```

> or in your case

```
if(assertdef(foo))
```

> or in another case

```
set(foo get_property(
))
```

> etc. This hits the parser and the argument processing in CMake but I
>   think it could be done. I guess I’m not sure if we *should* do it.
>   Open to opinions here.

Comment: I see, but this is again a sort of _how_. I am not interested on _how_ I may trick CMake, rather on _why_ it is the way it is, the leading idea.

Comment: It does the job, and it's easier to parse.

Comment: Very fine, you can use it, but this is not what I am asking in the question. I do not want a CMake function to return a value; I want to understand why it has been designed the way it is.

Comment: Because it's easy to parse, doing the job. There is no real reason.

Comment: @Caduchon Your comment does apply to a lot of features of a lot of languages. Anyway those features exist, because they make life easier to the users. _It does the job and it's easier to parse_ doesn't sound like the best reason ever indeed, even though I must admit that it could be the actual reason.